# In git, at what rate does the size increase if every character change is commit?

Tags: git, big-o, space-complexity

I'm trying to understand how Git works.

If I were to change (add or remove) character, save and commit that change until my code is written how will the size increase as the file becomes bigger? For example, what would be the size increase difference between commits 1 to 10, 1 to 100, 1 to 1 million even?

Also, does it become slower over time to commit changes? At which nth commit does it become unfeasible?

Answer (score 6):

You can try yourself:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -eu

chars=({a..z})

rm -rf git
mkdir git
cd git
git init
git config user.email name@example.com

for (( i = 0; i <= 10000 ; ++i )) ; do
    printf ${chars[RANDOM % 26]} >> a
    time git add a
    time git commit -m "Change $i"
    du -s .git
done
```

If it gets too slow, try running `git gc` or `git repack`.

Comment: Thank you, man, I feel stupid. You're a genius. What happens if I repack though?